# How get customers that didn't bought in last X months in Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, customer, reports

I want to get customers list that didn't bought in last X months in magento 1  or 2?

**Like:**

Last 12 months

Last 9 months

Last 20 months

Last 36 months

Comment: Filter the sales/order collection with the date range and get all the unique customer_ids. And then filter the customer collection with condition not in customer_ids.

Comment: Do you need SQL query for that?

Comment: I need collections of customers.

Answer (score 0):

in database of magento 2 there is a table ## sales_order ##  from there you take the customer details.

Comment: That is not a good idea. The customer can visit the site without placing order.

Comment: @AthulVijayan sorry its my mistake . you can actually take details from sales_order table